# Is it possible to have an array of unknown types?

Tags: c#, generics

```
public static bool Compare<T>(this T source, T other, params Expression<Func<T>>[] propertiesToSkip)
{
    PropertyInfo[] sourceProperties = source.GetType().GetProperties();
    List<string> lstPropertiesToSkip = (from x in propertiesToSkip select ((MemberExpression)((UnaryExpression)x.Body).Operand).Member.Name).ToList();
    return !(sourceProperties.Any(sourcePropertyInfo => !lstPropertiesToSkip.Contains(sourcePropertyInfo.Name) && (!sourcePropertyInfo.GetValue(source, null).Equals(sourcePropertyInfo.GetValue(other, null)))));
}
```

I want to be able to call this function by.

```
var source = new MyClass();
var other = new MyClass();
source.Compare<MyClass>(other, ()=>SkipProperty1, ()=>SkipProperty2);
```

The problem is ()=>SkipProperty1 and ()=>SkipProperty2 are not of type MyClass.
I need:

```
Compare <A,B,C,D...>  
params Expression<Func<T>>[] where T is A,B,C,D,E...
```

I have looked at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/), with fluent syntax.

```
public IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> ForMember(string name, Action<IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource>> memberOptions);

Mapper.CreateMap<MyClass, MyClass>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Property1, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Property2, opt => opt.Ignore()));
```

**- Can I change the signature of Compare to make the function work?**

**- Is there other way to solving this? For example using fluent syntax**

Note I don't want to send property names as strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to change the signature of your `param` arguments to be lambda expressions that return `object`. Something like this:

```
public static bool Compare<T>
  (this T source, T other, params Expression<Func<object>>[] propertiesToSkip)
```

This should work fine, because any .NET type can be cast or boxed to object. You'll need to slightly adjust your code to extract `PropertyInfo` from the lambda expressions (because there will be additional boxing or cast).

Using fluent syntax should work as well. You'll need some type to pass around:

```
class SkipComparison<T> {
  public T Source { get; set; }
  public T Other { get; set; }
  public List<PropertyInfo> PropertiesToSkip { get; set; }

  public SkipComparison<T> Skip<R>(Expression<Func<R>> f)
    // TODO: Extract property info, add it to 
    // 'PropertiesToSkip' and 'return this;'
  public bool Run()
    // TODO: Actually perform the comparison here
}
```

Your `Compare` method will return a new instance of this class with just `Source` and `Other` set and you'll use the `Skip` method to add additional properties to be skipped.

Comment: Although you should always try to avoid boxing and unboxing... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk(v=vs.80).aspx ;)

Comment: @PedroC88: There is no boxing/unboxing involved if you're working with lambda _expressions_. The code is never executed!